How can I track google search performance for my chrome extension listed on the chrome web store?
Basically the title. I feel like there should have been a much easier way to do this but I do not find any option anywhere. I am able to understand the incoming traffic thanks to google analytics but obviously I'd want to understand the exact phrases people are searching for to come to the extension listing on chrome web store.
I am just not sure how to verify ownership of the chrome web store listing which is like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/your-extension-id
Already tried chatGPT and it shows random answers for the verification part assuming that this is some website I have hosted somewhere. I correct one thing, then it accepts its mistake and goes on to another method making the same mistake and then eventually in the end asks me to be satisfied by GA.
I feel like Google Tags is the answer but I don't have much experience with that and I feel like in this case the relavant admin access rests with admins of Chrome Web Store and there might be some gaps because of that as well over there.
